# objective -c delegates syntax query

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to objective-c and pretty much confused with the way delegates are used. I came across this code and i would like to use it to clarify some of the doubts.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ProcessDataDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) processSuccessful: (BOOL)success;

@end

@interface ClassWithProtocol : NSObject 
{
  id <ProcessDataDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;

 -(void)startSomeProcess;

@end
```

Here, there are 2 references to the word "delegate" can anyone explain what it means when used in context with "id angled bracket delegate angled-bracket-closed" ??

Again, there is a property with name delegate. Should it not cause any kind of conflict ??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: IMHO there should be a protocol requirement on the property as well. The code will work as is, but I find it cleaner to write @property(retain)id<ProcessDataDelegate>delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is just one property, the one defined by `@property (retain) id delegate`; the other one is *(sort of)* private variable of the `NSObject` which is not a property in a objective-c sense... then, you have `@synthetize` keyword in your .m file, which expands the property.

The other notation, `id<protocol>` is telling, that delegate is expected to conform to a certain protocol.

You can access both from the class, but you can access only property from outside. Also, for a property, some other stuff is generated - in case of retain (when not using ARC), memory management routines.

To complete the *(confusion?)* lecture, there is a nice way to have class private properties, when you define them in .m file instead of .h in an anonymous category like:

```
@interface MyClass()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString privateString;

@end

@implementation
@synthetize privateString;

// ...

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
id <ProcessDataDelegate> delegate;
```

says that there is an instance variable called `delegate`, and it can be an object of any type that you like, as long as that object adopts the `ProcessDataDelegate` protocol.

The line later on that starts with @property is just declaring an Objective-C 2.0 property for that class that happens to have the same name as the instance variable. It is not a conflict. The declaration of the property is just a shortcut for getter/setter methods for the delegate instance variable.

More modern obj-c usage would be this:

```
@interface ClassWithProtocol : NSObject

@property (retain) id<ProcessDataDelegate> delegate;

- (void)startSomeProcess;

@end
```

You can read all about this stuff in [Apple's Objective-C language documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).